# CSS Filter is stopped by background

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter, background

OK let's say I have this

```
.test {
filter:DropShadow(Color=#000000, OffX=1, OffY=1);
}
```

Yes, it works fine. The text-shadow appears in Internet Explorer. However... if I add a background for color like so:

```
    .test {
    filter:DropShadow(Color=#000000, OffX=1, OffY=1);
    background:#ffffff;
}
```

Can you guess what happens? The filter goes way! However, if I ,once again, remove the background property... the filter (text-shadow) comes back!

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried placing the background attribute before the filter?

```
.test {
    background:#000000;
    filter:DropShadow(Color=#000000, OffX=1, OffY=1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ROFL, just realized your background and dropshadow colors are the same.  Could it just be that you can't tell it's showing up??

If not you might want to try this.

```
.test {
    background:#000000;
    filter:DropShadow(Color=#000000, OffX=1, OffY=1) !important;
}
```

Comment: Actaully, that's not the problem. The !important target didn't work.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is the z-index, but I'm not sure that would apply to the filters.

Comment: I assume your in a situation where you can't use the css3 dropshadow??  If so, the only other thing I can think of is to do it as an image, create the drop shadow in an image editor and put it on the background.  That's probably not what you wanted to hear, but that's all I've got. :-/